# What is the next step in use Xdebug

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug

I'm using PhpStorm and laravel 5. I have done the following steps below and have my laravel 5 project open. What must i do now to start debugging? I do not know the next steps in this process on the phpStorm side.

Instructions

```
Download xdebug-2.3.1.tgz
Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf xdebug-2.3.1.tgz
Run: cd xdebug-2.3.1

Run: phpize (See the FAQ if you don't have phpize.

As part of its output it should show:

Configuring for:
...
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525

If it does not, you are using the wrong phpize. Please follow this FAQ entry and skip the next step.
Run: ./configure
Run: make
Run: cp modules/xdebug.so
Edit /etc/php.ini and add the line
zend_extension = /xdebug.so
Restart the webserver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the tutorial for setting up phpstorm - https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-xdebug.html

You will also need to trigger the debugger in the browser -

The easiest Xdebug
This extension for Firefox was built to make debugging with an IDE easier. You can find the extension at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-easiest-xdebug/.

Xdebug Helper for Chrome
This extension for Chrome will help you to enable/disable debugging and profiling with a single click. You can find the extension at https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc.

Xdebug Toggler for Safari
This extension for Safari allows you to auto start Xdebug debugging from within Safari. You can get it from Github at https://github.com/benmatselby/xdebug-toggler.

Xdebug launcher for Opera
This extension for Opera allows you to start an Xdebug session from Opera.